# Hexo blog build error and the chic theme could not be found

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, travis-ci, hexo

When I push my hexo blog to GitHub, it doesn't work.

When I check the build message, the build with Jekyll show github-pages

```
227|Error: The chic theme could not be found
```

Of course, my blog contains the chic theme.

Some messages about my blog:

- I use Travis CI to build my blog, and my blog files save on hexo branch, the Travis CI builds blog files on the master branch.
- my blog link:https://github.com/plusmultiply0/plusmultiply0.github.io

I have searched the Internet to find the solution, but get no, for example, not with remote_theme. Could you help me?

I hope someone could help me solve the problem and help the blog build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to good person in v2ex,I found the solution to my problem.

You can add **a empty file named .nojekyll** to your repo, and everything will be ok.

Comment: Where in the repo should one add .nojekyll ?